# getting top users uploaded pictures using php

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

guys im using the laravel framework version 3 , i wanna to get the most 10 active users (who uploaded huge number of pictures) .
my tables structres :
*Users* :

```
id,username ..
```

*Images* :

```
id,user_id,views..
```

then i want to show the total of views of their pictures exmaple :
views of the pic 1 is : 150
views of the pic 2 is : 100
so the total of that users will be 250 and so on .
can anyone help plz?

Answer (score 0):

SQL query would be something like this:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) as numPics,
  SUM(p.views) as totalViews
FROM
  pics p
INNER JOIN
  users u
ON
  p.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY p.user_id
ORDER BY numPics DESC LIMIT 10
```

However, depending on how much data you have, I strongly suggest avoiding this kind of aggregation in real-time and would seek to cache it.

Comment: the query doesn't works i got this error :
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) as numPics,  SUM(p.views) as totalViews FROM  images p INNER JOIN  users u ON' at line 1

SQL: SELECT  COUNT(p.*) as numPics,  SUM(p.views) as totalViews FROM  images p INNER JOIN  users u ON  p.user_id = u.id GROUP BY p.user_id ORDER BY numPics DESC LIMIT 10

Bindings: array (
)

Comment: thanks , when i try to foreach the results and echo $user['numPics'] it give me this error :
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: try echo $user->numPics - your ORM is sending the values back as an object not an array.

Comment: i got this error dear : Undefined property: stdClass::$numPics